# Square Coin on a Square Grid

Tags: probability

A 1-inch-square coin is thrown on a table covered with a grid of lines two inches apart. What is the probability the coin lands in a square without touching any of the lines of the grid? It is similar to an earlier circular coin question .

Comment: Hint: Think about where the center of the coin could land within the square.

Comment: the corner and the edges are not symmetric. It is a square coin .

Comment: I assume you mean the ending orientation of your square coin is random (i.e. no need to be axis aligned with the grid). If yes, please state this explicitly in your question.

Comment: @achillehui Let us assume that the orientation is random. (Let us forget for some time what he meant to ask) The answer seems really tricky to calculate. Or is there some easy manipulation?

Comment: @UserNotFound It is not that hard. The squares has two diagonals, the grid has two axis. There are 4 possible angles formed from them. If $\theta$ is the smallest one among these 4 angles, then $\theta$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,\pi/4]$. For given $\theta$, the  conditional probability the the coin touch the grid is a very simple. Taking averages over $\theta$ will give one the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the unit square is tilted by the angle $\alpha\in\bigl[0,{\pi\over2}\bigr]$ with respect to the axes its horizontal and its vertical extensions are $w(\alpha)=\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha$. For the purposes of this problem it is then an axis aligned square of side length $w(\alpha)$. The probability that a horizontal grid line hits this square  is ${w(\alpha)\over2}$, and the probability $p(\alpha)$ that neither a horizontal nor a vertical gridline hits the square is given by
$$p(\alpha)=\left(1-{w(\alpha)\over2}\right)^2\ .$$Taking the average over $\alpha\in\bigl[0,{\pi\over2}\bigr]$ we obtain the probability $P$ the OP is looking for:
$$P={2\over\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} p(\alpha)\>d\alpha={5\over4}-{7\over2\pi}=0.135\,915\ .$$

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines but with fixed coordinates.I assumed one of the corners of square as (x,y) and the orientation of square as α then i wrote 4 inequalities with respect to other corners and i was stuck. Can you please help me out there....

Comment: Got your method finally. Beautiful Answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$. as  Donald Splutterwit hinted, the area that the coin can land in is a $1\times 1=1$-inch area centered on the middle of the square. since the area of each square is $2\times 2=4$, the odds that a square coin lands where you depict is $\frac{1\times 1}{2\times 2}=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Your answer is only considering that coin can fall aligned to the grid which is not the case ( although not explicitly mentioned in the question).